# Видоизменить GET параметры перед отправкой формы

Tags: javascript, get

Есть некая форма

```
<form method="GET" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="first-option">
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="second-option">
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="third-option">
<input type="submit" value="GO!">
</form>
```

Количество чекбоксов может быть разным.
Если выполнить отправку, то адресная строка получится такая:

> /?param=first-optin&param=second-option&param=third-option

Чтобы  дальнейшем иметь возможно обработать данный запрос, строку нужно привести к такому виду:

> /?param=first-option-or-second-option-or-third-option

То есть поместить в один параметр, а значения разделить при помощи конструкции -or-.

Это можно как-то сделать с помощью js, чтобы отправлять уже в нужном виде?

**UPD**
Самому удалось собрать вот такой фарш из jquery-кода и чистого js. Работает правильно, но выглядит ужасно.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
        var queryString = $(this).serialize();

        if (queryString) {
            var vars = [];
            var arr = queryString.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (q = arr[i].split('='))
                vars[i] = decodeURIComponent(q[1]);
            }
            vars = vars.join('-or-');

            window.location.search = '?param='+vars;
        }else{
            window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Вопросы, которые меня интересовали изначально:
 1. Можно ли на js получить сформированную get-строку из формы, до её
    отправки, а не собирать данные полей?
 2. Можно ли изменить её видоизменить и вернуть браузеру, а не
    перенаправлять при помощи `window.location`?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms - хорошая статья по кодировкам. Что вам мешает обработать первую запись?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, спасибо за ссылку. Статью изучил, но не сказал бы, что она мне помогла решить задачу. Свой первый пост я несколько дополнил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, данные из формы должны отправиться на страницу **1.html**:

```html
<form method="GET" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="first-option">
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="second-option">
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="third-option">
<input type="submit" value="GO!" onclick="sending(); return false">
</form>
<script>
var action = "1.html"; // страница перенаправления
var allcheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
function sending(){
 var out = "";
 for(i = 0; i < allcheckbox.length - 1; i ++) if(allcheckbox[i].checked)out += "-or-" + allcheckbox[i].value;
 location.href = action + "?param=" + out.substring(4);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, короткий и чистый код) Несколько видоизменю его, перехода на другую страницу не будет, да и больше нравится отлавливать сабмит, нежели вешать онклик на саму кнопку. Мне не очень понятно, почему если распечатать в консоль содержимое переменной `allcheckbox`, то мы получим два раза первый инпут в логе? И allcheckbox.length - 1 делается, чтобы вычесть инпут-сабмит?

Comment: Да, так как сабмит не принимает участия в формировании гетзапроса. Если бы он был не input, а button, то это было бы не нужно. А когда я распечатываю, всё верно получается.